# Why do I need to set the Visibility of LinkButton in a ListView Layout in the LayoutCreated event instead of directly on the LinkButton?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView control and in the LayoutTemplate I have a LinkButton.  I tried setting the Visible property to <%# IsUserAdmin %>, where IsUserAdmin is a method which returns true or false depending on whether the user is an admin or not and sets the visibility of the control, but I found out that this does not work for the LayoutTemplate and instead of I have to go to the LayoutCreated event and get the control and then set its visibility.  I am curious why I have to do it this way with a control in the LayoutTemplate?  I can use the <%# IsUserAdmin %> on the Visible property of a control in the ItemTemplate with no problem.  I was thinking it would actually be easier for the LayoutTemplate because there is only 1 control generated instead of multiple controls for the ItemTemplates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `<%= IsUserAdmin %>` instead of `<%# %>` deliver the expected behavior?

You shouldn't use `<%# %>` in non-databound situations. So for manipulating properties on objects that are just on your form use `<%= %>`. This'd work as long as `IsUserAdmin` is a public property.

Comment: IsUserAdmin is a public method and I have not tried <%= %>.  I wasn't clear on what the difference betwen <%# %> was and what <%= %> was.

Comment: Use <%= IsUserAdmin.ToString() %> as this tag indicates a string value.